# How to Retrieve and Use Glossary Entry Value in `fp` Package for Calculations?

Tags: glossaries, fp

I intend to utilize the numerical value `590.98` stored in the glossary entry `PClabel` for subsequent calculations. My approach was to retrieve the value using `\glsuseri{PClabel}` and incorporate it into an `fp` variable named `\PricePC` as follows: `\FPset\PricePC{ \glsuseri{PClabel} }`. Unfortunately, this method does not seem to work. Does anyone have an alternative solution or suggestion on how to achieve this? Please refer to the code snippet below:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Include packages:
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fp}

%% Define glossary entry:
\newglossaryentry{PClabel}{                     % label
    name={Personal Computer},                   % name
    description={designed for individual use},  % description
    user1={590.98},                             % price
    user2={CHF},                                % currency 
}

\begin{document}
    
    The price of the \glsentryname{PClabel}
    is \glsuseri{PClabel} \glsuserii{PClabel}.
    
    %% Using the price for further calculations using the 'fp' package
    %% How can I use \glsuseri{PClabel} as an argument for \FPset\PricePC{...}?
    
    \FPset\PricePC{590.98}  % replacing 590.98 by \glsuseri{PClabel} does not work                  
    
    The price of the \glsentryname{PClabel} 
    stored \texttt{PricePC}
    is \PricePC\ \glsuserii{PClabel}.
        
\end{document}
```

**OUTCOME**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an expandable version of the commands. You need to ensure that the contents of the field has the right type (and exists).

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Include packages:
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fp}

%% Define glossary entry:
\newglossaryentry{PClabel}{                     % label
    name={Personal Computer},                   % name
    description={designed for individual use},  % description
    user1={590.98},                             % price
    user2={CHF},                                % currency
}

\newcommand{\expandgls}[2]{\UseName{glo@\detokenize{#1}@#2}}

\begin{document}

The price of the \glsentryname{PClabel}
is \glsuseri{PClabel} \glsuserii{PClabel}.

%% Using the price for further calculations using the 'fp' package
%% How can I use \glsuseri{PClabel} as an argument for \FPset\PricePC{...}?

\FPset\PricePC{\expandgls{PClabel}{useri}}

The price of the \glsentryname{PClabel}
stored \texttt{PricePC}
is \PricePC\ \glsuserii{PClabel}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also avoid `fp`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Include packages:
\usepackage{glossaries}

%% Define glossary entry:
\newglossaryentry{PClabel}{                     % label
    name={Personal Computer},                   % name
    description={designed for individual use},  % description
    user1={590.98},                             % price
    user2={CHF},                                % currency
}

\newcommand{\expandgls}[2]{\UseName{glo@\detokenize{#1}@#2}}

\begin{document}

The price of the \glsentryname{PClabel}
is \glsuseri{PClabel} \glsuserii{PClabel}.

The 20\% discounted price of the \glsentryname{PClabel} 
is \fpeval{round(\expandgls{PClabel}{useri}*0.80,2)} \glsuserii{PClabel}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: the value contained in the field `foo` of the entry `baz` is stored in the macro `\glo@baz@foo`; the entry name is detokenized, in case it contains “risky” characters.

Comment: glossaries has expandable commands to retrieve the fields, but one needs an additional expansion step with `\FPset`:  `\ExpandArgs{No}\FPset\PricePC{\glsentryuseri{PClabel}}`